# Search box display issues on Search Results Page w/ Search Webpart

Tags: 2013, search-results

I'm having an issue with the .ms-srch-sbLarge class on search result pages.  I have a custom masterpage with the small Searchbox snippet rendered from Design Manager which is utilizing my css styles.  If a user goes on a Search results page and uses the search box on a search webpart, it copies the .ms-srch-sbLarge class to my search control and screws up the display.  I am trying to either override the CSS [as denoted below changing the specificity which does nothing], or to remove that class completely from the search control within my navigation only.  My assumption is that the reason the styles aren't working is because of something in the js fired when someone hits the enter button in the search input within the actual webpart.

Here is the css I am using to target the div and input for the Search control:

```
div#ct100_ct148_csr_sboxdiv.ms-srch-sbLarge.ms-srch-sb-border {border-radius: 10px; width: 250px; background:#343a5d; height:25px; color: #fff; font-size:1em;}
input#ct100_ct148_csr_sboxdiv.ms-textLarge.ms-srch-sbLarge-fullWidth{ width:200px; background-color:transparent; padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px; height:18px; outline-style:none; border-style:none; display:inline-block; font:inherit; }
a#ct100_ct148_csr_SearchLink.ms-srch-sb-searchLink {height:20px; width:20px;}
```

Please see the images to denote what it showcased in the dev tools AFTER making an entry in the Search webpart input control.  [Also note, the pictures that demonstrate what is happening].

I have tried changing the specificity of the css and using jQuery to target the .ms-srch-sbLarge class only on the elements in the header.  the jQuery does not render - again, I am assuming bc I have it set to document.ready.

[image: Display Issue on Search]

[image: CSS in DevTools]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! OP (Original Poster) found the cause... he read `ctl00` as `ct100`

---

You can't block CSS being applied

You **can** increase [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to overrule other (later applied) CSS

```
.ms-srch-sbLarge.ms-srch-sbLarge{
  color:red;
}
```

Note SharePoint uses this sometimes as well... then raise the specificity of your selector:

```
.ms-srch-sbLarge.ms-srch-sbLarge.ms-srch-sbLarge{
  color:red;
}
```

Those who don't understand CSS will use `!important`, but that totally destroys all capabilities for other selectors to apply formatting

### Re: comments

[CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) can only be overruled when code sets inline styles (not classes!) on an element. If SP adds a class later it can always be overruled by previous loaded selectors with a higher [Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Here is a screenshot where I applied higher [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) (marked blue) to counter what SP applies in `.ms-srch-sbLarge`

That class does **not** control the INPUT, so you have to counter more of SharePoints CSS to get what you want

[image]

#### CSS Selectors

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

is a must read,

**With [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) you can change any CSS any time**

the only thing that trumps Specificity is (inline) `style=" "` attributes on Elements.
That is why CSS designers hate inline styles.

### Last resort

If you still have problems with existing CSS you can dive into `document.stylesheets` with JavaScript, disable stylesheets or dive deeper into `CSSrules` of each stylesheet to delete individual rules

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: The issue here for me is that the .ms-srch-sbLarge class is also applied to the Search webpart in the content area.   The Search Results delegate control overrides all the Searchboxes on the page, thus displaying a huge searchbox in my header, which screws up the custom masterpage.

I got around this by just using jQuery to target that class in my #topBar header and removing it, then adding .ms-srch-sb to render it as it should.  This seemed the easiest way to remove the class from only the topBar w/o affecting the Searchbox in webparts.

Comment: or include ``#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_csr_sbox`` in the CSS selector to only target the one input box. That by itself overrules SharePoints CSS Specificity

Comment: thanks, however, that doesn't work because it's not the input box where the styling is applied.  it is the div... which has the .ms-srch-sbLarge class controlling how the box is rendered.  unless i am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Sorry.. But that DIV has an id as well.. ``ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_csr_sboxdiv`` on SharePoint Online

Comment: ah gotcha... i still run into the issue with the .ms-srch-sbLarge class applied to the search icon image, which is the real issue because that image is huge and pushes the navigation menu down.

Comment: Once you have an entry point your can target any child element. It all comes down to properly using CSS Selectors and understanding Specificity eg. ``#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_csr_sboxdiv  > img { max-height:20px}``

Comment: Thanks for your help - but that's not the problem  I am having.  It doesn't matter what I change the CSS to, the SP.js that runs seems to override it regardless.  This is bc of the search delegate ctrl.  Thanks for your input, however.

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try that and get back to you. Have s good weekend.

Comment: Thanks again for attempting to help - unf, again, this does not work.  I can change the specificity until my fingers are numb; I too have sat there & successfully changed the elements in the dev tools only to see the styles not applied once the css file is updated.  Presumably, there is something going on with the actual JS that is fired once a search is made from that webpart.  I do not even see my styles rendered in the dev window with strikethroughs to indicate the styles are being overridden.

Comment: I think I need to make a search css file and have it loaded AFTER the search center css file loads in the actual master page.

Comment: I think you still do not understand what CSS Specificity is, The whole point of CSS Specificitiy is that it does **not** matter in what order CSS loads

Comment: No I know what it is; it just isn't working.  Literally, the styles I applied should work.. they do not.  ID trumps classes.  If I specify the input with an ID of ct100_ct148_csr_sbox that SHOULD work, yes?   It works in dev tools, but when I update the file.. nope.  If I add #ct100_ct148_csr_sbox and then do .ms-srch-sbLarge.ms-srch-sbLarge that does not work at all even in dev tools.  Specificity itself is not lost on me, perhaps how to apply it to this PARTICULAR situation is the issue I am having.

Comment: I also want to note that in devtools the jQuery option works as well... in production, it does not.

Comment: That's weird..  with production you mean Console closed? Or a different env? Sounds like something else is going on, check Netwokr Tab, are your CSS changes even loaded?

Comment: ...holy shiitake. i figured out what it was and now I feel incredibly stupid.  What we were interpreting as "#ct100" is actually #CTL00... the "1" is a lowercase letter L.  :|  shoots self in the foot.  I'm going to mark yours as an answer with the 50 pts just bc I appreciate you working with me all of this time.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you glad I made it a personal 2017 mission to educate people about CSS Specificity..even if it takes a Draconian approach... Don't worry, we all still make mistakes like these every week... it is called learning.. Once you stop making mistakes and think you know it all, you are doomed